# Open all youtube links with different app

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser, url

I'm looking for a solution on macOS to make all `youtube.com` or `youtu.be` links automatically open in another app, **decided by me**, like `/Applications/Brave Browser.app` for example. All while keeping Safari my default browser for all other links.

Here's what I want to happen:

- Clicking on a apple.com link inside Mail.app should load Apple's site in Safari
- Clicking on a youtube.com link inside Twitter.app should load youtube in Brave Browser
- Clicking on a youtube.com link inside Firefox.app should load youtube in Brave Browser
- Clicking on a stackoverflow.com link inside Safari should load stackoverflow in Safari.
- Clicking on a youtu.be link inside a Safari page should load youtube in Brave Browser.

Why I suspect this kind of behavior should be possible: When you install for example Twitter's app, and click any link that refers to twitter.com, it'll ask once to open all twitter links in the app:

[image: clicking a twitter link]

Perhaps creating a new app for this is a solution? One that registers any user-added [URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app) and forwards it to the app of choice?

Comment: The trouble with this idea is that all your links have the same existing scheme - `https:`- so can only be registered to one default app.

Comment: The Twitter example is also using https, but clicking any twitter.com link still opens my installed Twitter.app

Comment: Twitter as an app can register itself to open Twitter-only links, unfortunately Safari can't be made to do so at runtime.